# Altering the Center of Rotation of a ScatterViewItem

Tags: wpf, touch, pixelsense, scatterview

By default, when manipulating a ScatterViewItem control it will rotate about its own center point.

Is there any way to alter this such that the control rotates about another point, for example rotate about its own top left corner?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported by the ScatterViewItem control. Technically I think it's just adjusting the rendertransform as it's being manipulated, but a simple test of altering that didn't seem to work. It's likely resetting it at runtime. Not sure why you need this functionality (it seems like it wouldn't feel very natural), but I'd recommend creating a custom control to do it.